# What standards are available for classifying Organizations and Businesses?

Tags: standards, classification

I'm looking to create directory and I would like to know what standards are available for classifying businesses, professions, and organizations?

Answer (score 2):

Two standards are big in the USA, but there may be many others

- [North American Industry Classification System (NAICS)](http://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/sssd/naics/naicsrch?chart=2012)
- [Standard Industrial Classification (SIC) (older US standard)](https://www.osha.gov/pls/imis/sic_manual.html)

You can read about [these two standards here](http://www.census.gov/eos/www/naics/).

Also, internationally there is the [International Standard Industrial Classification of All Economic Activities (ISIC)](http://unstats.un.org/unsd/cr/registry/regcst.asp?Cl=27) a production by the United Nations. This has the advantage of being internationlized (available in other langauges). You can find ISIC for [download here](http://unstats.un.org/unsd/cr/registry/regdnld.asp?Lg=1).

Also see the other nation-specific standards,

- [Australian and New Zealand Standard Industrial Classification (ANZSIC)](http://www.abs.gov.au/ausstats/abs@.nsf/ViewContent?readform&view=DirClassManualsbyTopic&Action=Expand&Num=6.1.2)
- Nomenclature of Economic Activities (NACE) (a subset of ISIC with further divisions for "European Economies")
- [Japanese Industrial Standards Committee (JSIC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_Industrial_Standards_Committee)

Answer (score 1):

[Microformats](http://microformats.org/)
[Microdata](https://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/)
[Schema](http://schema.org/)
[QB4OLAP - Business Intelligence over Linked Data.](http://lorenae.github.io/qb4olap/)
[FIBO - Financial Industry Business Ontology](https://www.w3.org/community/fibo/)
[XBRL - eXtensible Business Reporting Language](https://www.xbrl.org/)

Always helpful to peruse [LOV - Linked Open Vocabularies](https://lov.okfn.org/dataset/lov/).

Comment: Those aren't really standards for classification. They're standards for markup and other stuff.

Comment: i get your point but that doesn't mean they are mutually exclusive. they're also required if you're going to go from the web of documents to the web of data.

Comment: And, what makes you think this has anything to do with the web of documents or the web of data? It has to do with classification standards for companies. It's not mutually exclusive. But, it's totally unrelated to your answer in every way.

Comment: hello evan, this is open data stack exchange, where everything has to do with lod in one way, shape, or form. again, i got your point, but my answer is still correct and relevant. if you don't like it, perhaps reword your question so that it fits the finely tuned view you are seeking.